# Docker compose tries to create duplicate container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker Compose to setup multiple services so that they can talk to each over a common network.  I am running into an issue when I call command `docker-compose up`

Docker Version: Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea

Error:

```
Creating network "was-kerberos-database_krbnet" with the default driver
Creating was-kerberos-database_kerberos_1 ...
Creating was-kerberos-database_websphere_1 ...
Creating was-kerberos-database_websphere_1 ... error

ERROR: for was-kerberos-database_websphere_1  Cannot start service websphere: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoinCreating was-kerberos-database_kerberos_1  ... done
isten tcp 0.0.0.0:9443: bind: address already in use
Creating was-kerberos-database_db2_1       ... done

ERROR: for websphere  Cannot start service websphere: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint was-kerberos-database_websphere_1 (e4706a4f9ec7bb5f2ab81078c270d15c786999edf5dc8a2a235e316b62cc39da): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9443: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

It looks like docker compose is trying to bring up two duplicate instances of the `was-kerberos-database_websphere_1` instance.  Then is running into an issue because the same port is bound on both.

```
version: '3'
volumes:
    krb5kdc-data:
services:
  websphere:
    build: websphere-traditional
    ports:
      - "9043:9043"
      - "9443:9443"
      - "9080:9080"
    environment:
      - KRB5_REALM=EXAMPLE.COM
      - KRB5_KDC=kerberos
      - ENABLE_BASIC_LOGGING=true
    volumes:
      - ./trace/twas/logs:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs
    networks:
      krbnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.2
  db2:
    build: db2
    ports:
      - "50000:50000"
    environment:
      - KRB5_REALM=EXAMPLE.COM
      - KRB5_KDC=kerberos
    privileged: True
    depends_on: 
      - "kerberos"
    networks:
      krbnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5
  kerberos:
    build: kdc-server
    ports:
      - "88:88"
      - "464:464"
      - "749:749"
    environment:
      - KRB5_REALM=EXAMPLE.COM
      - KRB5_KDC=localhost
      - KRB5_PASS=password
    volumes:
      - krb5kdc-data:/var/lib/krb5kdc
    networks:
      krbnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.9
networks:
  krbnet:   
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
```

I have run `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 9443` to see if anything else is using this port, and nothing is.

Comment: what is the output of these commands: `docker ps -a` and `sudo netstat -tulnp`

Comment: That is very strange. I'm not sure but I wonder the hyphen in the build name is causing a problem? Maybe ```build: websphere-traditional``` is being interpreted as ```build: websphere```? Is it possible to use an image name with an underscore rather than a hyphen to see whether it works? It's a very strange issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I can give it a try.  I did end up changing this file to use a different port `49443:9443`. Which did work, and everything started correctly.  But, again no other processes are using that port so I am not sure where the conflict would be.

Comment: That's so weird. Well done on finding a workaround.